# Can't figure how to stop dictionary keys from overwriting themselves

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary, parsing

I'm trying to create a dictionary and my dictionary keys keep overwriting themselves. I don't understand how I can handle this issue.

Here's the script:

```
import MDAnalysis as mda


u = mda.Universe('rps5.prmtop', 'rps5.inpcrd')

ca = u.select_atoms('protein')

charges = ca.charges
atom_types = ca.names
resnames = ca.resnames


charge_dict = {}

for i in range(len(charges)):
    #print(i+1 ,resnames[i], atom_types[i], charges[i])
    charge_dict[resnames[i]] =  {}
    charge_dict[resnames[i]][atom_types[i]] = charges[i]

print(charge_dict)
```

The **charges**, **atom_types** and **resnames** are all lists, with the same number of elements.

I want my dictionary to look like this: ***charge_dict[resname][atom_types] = charges*** (charge_dict['MET']['CA'] = 0.32198, for example).

Could you please help me with this issue?

Comment: Does resnames contain duplicate entries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without actually seeing a complete problem description, my guess is that your final result is that each `charge_dict[name]` is a dictionary with just one key. That's not because the keys  "overwrite themselves". Your program overwrites them explicitly: `charge_dict[resnames[i]] =  {}`.

What you want is to only reset the value for that key if it is not already set. You could easily do that by first testing `if resnames[i] not in charge_dict:`, but the Python standard library provides an even simpler mechanism: [`collections.defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict). A `defaultdict` is a dictionary with an associated default value creator. So you can do the following:

```py
from collections import defaultdict
charge_dict = defaultdict(dict)
```

After that, you won't need to worry about initializing `charge_dict[name]` because a new dictionary will automatically spring into existence when the default value function (`dict`) is called.